# Karma-angular e2e cli test scripts fails to run (while tests do run from the browser)

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

in the browser everything works: `localhost:8002/test/e2e/runner.html`

while in the cli `./scripts/e2e-test.sh` it fails with:

The config:

```
module.exports = function(config){
    config.set({


    basePath : '../',

    files : [
        'test/e2e/**/*.js'
    ],

    autoWatch : false,

    browsers : ['Chrome'],

    frameworks: ['ng-scenario'],

    singleRun : true,

    proxies : {
      '/': 'http://localhost:8002/#' //added the hash as a test.. didn't help
    },

    plugins : [
            'karma-junit-reporter',
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-firefox-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-ng-scenario'    
            ],

    junitReporter : {
      outputFile: 'test_out/e2e.xml',
      suite: 'e2e'
    }

})}
```

the test running script:

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE_DIR=`dirname $0`

echo ""
echo "Starting Karma Server (http://karma-runner.github.io)"
echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------"

karma start $BASE_DIR/../config/karma-e2e.conf.js $*
```

The failure message:

```
WARN [config]: "/" is proxied, you should probably change urlRoot to avoid conflicts
WARN [proxy]: proxy "http://localhost:8002/#" normalized to "http://localhost:8002/#/"
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 30.0.1599 (Linux)]: Connected on socket qt_XZkiY6ZC2o-f86Ln-
WARN [proxy]: failed to proxy /app/index.html ([object Object])
```

using ubuntu 13 (and yes I changed the web-server.js script default port to 8002)
I'll be glad for help or a direction..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issued  turned out to be the need to run `` `./scripts/webserver `` along the test runner.. quite obvious when I think of if. Also I have some memory that earlier versions of angular didn't need that. Nevermind